# subprocess ls examples/* no fuch file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> child = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "examples/*"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> ls: examples/*: No such file or directory
```

But from terminal it works

```
Beagle:kumarshubham$ ls examples/*
examples/convert_greyscale.py       examples/feat_det_harris_corner.py  examples/read_display_image.py
examples/example_set_roi.py     examples/manipulate_img_matplotlib.py   examples/remove_matplotlib_cache.py
```

Can one guide me where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen(["cd /to-your-PATH/; ls", "examples/*"],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
child.stdout.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of (*) wild card usage. You need to supply shell=True to execute the command through shell interpreter

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> child = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "examples/*"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `shell=True` in your `Popen` call even if `*` is useless in your case, `ls examples/` should return the same output:

```
child = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "examples/*"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Plus, more pythonic approach could be:

```
import os
os.listdir('examples')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use additional parameter shell=True, then it would look:

```
child = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "examples/*"], shell=True,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

NB! even this will work, - according to official python documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html using shell=True might be a security issue.